# this.NavigationController is null

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I m using `Xamarin` for `iOS`, `Xamarin Studio v5.7.1`

I having a small problem with the NavigationController.

I m pushing a ViewController programmatically like this:

```
ProfileViewController profileVC = ProfileViewController.ProfileViewControllerFromNib (this);

navController.PushViewController (profileVC, true)
```

And in the `ViewDidLoad` inside the `ProfileViewController` the NavigationController is `null`.

I thought to change the `segue` style to push like [this smart guy said](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13534/navigationcontroller-is-null?) but with no success.

Any help will super welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need to set storyboardId for view controller and configure in appdelegate.cs

Comment: No storyboard usage mate...

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I've got a INavigationService MVVM approach that has exactly this problem.

Comment: Yes, stopped using Xamarin and move to React-Native :), Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Did you set the RootNavigationController of the window in your AppDelegate?

```
window.RootViewController = _rootNavigationController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

Comment: Yep, I did... And this is not an answer to my question :/